# ipython notebook can not show multiple charts with d3js or nvd3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nvd3.js

If I tried to show the chart in 1st cell,

Then tried to show the same type chart in 2nd cell,

The second time will show nothing

#### The output html by python-nvd3 can not be shown

https://gist.github.com/poc7667/0f2203231fa6d01a3f39

#### The output on iPython notebook looks terrible(it is so narrow).

[image]

#### CODE

```
# load nvd3
import random
from IPython import display as d
import nvd3
nvd3.ipynb.initialize_javascript(use_remote=True)


chart3=nvd3.lineWithFocusChart(name="focusChart",height=600)
xdata = [ i['_id'] for i in DATA_SOURCE ]
ydata = [ i['count'] for i in DATA_SOURCE ]
chart3.add_serie(x=xdata,y=ydata,name="monthly allergic", x_is_date=True, x_axis_format="%Y/%m/%d")
chart3.buildhtml()
chart3

with open('demo3.html','w') as f:    
    f.write(chart3.htmlcontent)
```

#### Version of  iPython and nvd3

```
% pip3 list | grep ipython                                                                                                     (git)-[master]
ipython (3.1.0)
python-nvd3 (0.13.8)
```

Comment: It is a known issue that setting the width of the svg directly doesn't work. You have to set the width CSS property of the svg to set the chart's width: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/810

Comment: I didn't understand what you said about 1st and 2nd cells.

Comment: HI @RenatoUtsch if you print the chart twice, it won't show the chart second time

Comment: Are you creating a new container for the second chart? If you are just updating a chart you shouldn't create it again. If you create a new one, you should use a new container.

Answer (score 0):

Provide different **name** when you create second chart

```
    chart3=nvd3.lineWithFocusChart(name="some_other_name",height=600)
```

Name provided here is used as id for the container div of chart, giving different name shall solve this. This works for me, hope it helps you.